# adding a single backslash to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of strings that is storing values that I am going to print to a properties file. I want to append a backslash to the end of each line so I can have multi-line values. To put the values in the ArrayList I do this:

```
arrayListName.add(value + '\\');
```

It produces "value\\" in my ArrayList which ends up with four backslashes in the file. This:

```
arrayListName.add(value + '');
```

produces just "value", so there are no backslashes attached to value. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are you viewing the data in debug?  Trying printing the value to the terminal.  Are there two backslashes then?

Comment: that i was. Thanks! now I was actually incorrect it prints 4 backslashes into the file when there is only 1 in the arraylist...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're viewing your data in debug, you'll see two backslashes.

[image]

But if you print the data out, there will not be two backslashes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "value\\";
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Results:

```
value\
```

Comment: yeah this was my issue, now i guess ill have to figure out why it prints 4 backslashes into the file.